# Multiple Controller Definition leading to scope diifculty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Web application which is structured in a way that I need two controllers.

Its defination is as follows :-

```
var ZApp = angular.module('ZApp',['ngRoute','Zcontrollers','ngSanitize','ZControllers']);
```

The first controller included in index.html is :-

```
var zz = angular.module('ZControllers',['ngAnimate','ngImgCrop','webcam'])
zz.controller('MainController', MainController);
```

and second Controller is :-

```
zz.controller('EntController', EntController);
```

In some javascript file i am trying to access both the scopes of controllers and console them out.

But the Second Controller Scope is coming out to be empty however the first controller works fine.

Here is the code :-

```
if(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="MainController as main"]')){
        var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="MainController as main"]'));
        console.log(elem.scope()) //works fine
    }
    else if(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="EntController as ent"]')){
        var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="EntController as ent"]'));

        console.log(elem.scope());  //Comes empty
    }
```

Comment: What you want to acheive exactly ? access $scope variable in another controller

Comment: Wanting to access scopes of both the controllers in some javascript file.